# C# propery closing of an application when a form is still open

Tags: c#, winforms

What's the proper way to close application with clicking on X in built in menu strip. Let's say that my Form1 opens Form2, when I close my Form2 my Form 1 stays open. What I want to achieve is that my application stops when I close my Form2. Does anybody know how to achieve this and how to reference it to X button on built in menu strip.

Comment: Are you using winforms/wpf/xamarin? What does visual Studio have anything to do with your problem? And comon the tag "formclosing" seriously?

Comment: ``Environment.Exit`` should work for some cases. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am using winforms, I am still a beginner so I am sorry for my "stupid tag".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Application.Exit();
```

In case it doesn't work, you have to provide more information and be more specific with code

Answer (score 0):

In `Form2` you could Register to the `Closing` Event in constructor something like this:

```
public Form2()
{
    this.FormClosing += Form_OnClosing;
}
```

Then in the event close the `Form1` and/or exit the application

```
private void Form_OnClosing(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Application.OpenForms[0].Close();
    Application.Exit();
    Environment.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

`form2  F2 = new form2();
F2.ShowDialog()`
I think you have a trouble with create new form children